# how to add token value to URL and pass it without allowing any extra characters to be added?

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies, encryption, token

Hi I am trying to get token value from cookie and add it to the URL but extra characters like *(asterisk) are being added. please help me how should i pass my token value in URL without adding any characters.

here is my javascript code

```
 urls.put("AppName", "javascript:submitApplication()");

 function submitApplication() {

 var cookieToken = "SSOCookie";
 var newToken = GetCookie(cookieToken);

myWindow = window.open(myhost + "/webapp/sso?ssotype=type1&appname=APP1&mode=ARD&newToken="+newToken,'ApplicationName');

myWindow.focus();
}
```

My newToken value is added with stars as below

https://test.test1.com/webapp/sso?ssotype=type1&appname=APP1&mode=ARD&newToken=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczjfZ-64LqYUNHjjYVmu13iznLg1gKZoas.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABM2MTI2ODc1MDg4MDc4MzE0NjI0AAJTMQACMDY.**

But i want this to be passed as ( without adding any characters)

https://test.test1.com/webapp/sso?ssotype=type1&appname=APP1&mode=ARD&newToken=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczjfZ-64LqYUNHjjYVmu13iznLg1gKZoas.AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABM2MTI2ODc1MDg4MDc4MzE0NjI0AAJTMQACMDY.

Please help me how can i pass this token value in URL without allowing any extra characters to be added . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I would do something like this:**

Make a function that accepts a cookie name, to retrieve the cookie you're looking for.

```
function getCookie(cookieName) {
var name = cookieName + '=';
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
return '';
}
```

Then whenever you need to get that cookie, you just need to declare a variable and call that function.

```
var myCookie = getCookie('name_of_the_cookie');
```

Add the cookie to the url.

```
var basicUrl = 'https://www.google.dk';
var fullUrl = basicUrl + '/' + myCookie;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. My "newToken: value has a correct token value ( without *) in submitApplication() function but * are being added once after passing i,e in URL it appears. Pls advise

Comment: That is weird. I am doing right as described above, and works just perfectly. Do you have any relevant code that you have not posted? I do not see any mistake in the code snippet you have provided. Try and console.log(newToken) and see what the value of it is right after you retrieved it, or show it in the developers tool (application --> cookies --> your site)

Comment: Actually this happens only in OpenAM  environment, Could you please advise me anyway like encryption, or passing value through post form so that value is passed without any modifications.

Comment: I have no experience with OpenAM and therefor no idea of its behaviour, sorry :-( Will shout up if I get an idea of a solution.